# parallel computing in mirt

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a 3-factor mirt() on 10,000 polytomous items (3 categories each, graded) in Windows (no missing data; method="EM"). Obviously it's taking a very long time, so how can I decrease that computation time. I have many compute cores available and noticed there is a mirtCluster() function in mirt, but I've found things are often more complicated in Windows. I've searched pretty thoroughly for ways to use the 'parallel' or 'snow' packages directly for this, but there always seems to be some complication with doing it in Windows. Any suggestions?  My code is simply:

```
library(mirt)

x <- read.csv("file_with_10000_items.csv")

mod <- mirt(x,3)
```

Thanks!